# Get data in action page

Tags: php

I have created two submit buttons in a form in b.php with method POST and action to another page a.php .Now I want to display, which one has been clicked by the user in page b.php.Like ---

### under b.php

```
<form action="a.php" method="POST">
<input type="submit" name="c" value="c">
<input type="submit" name="d" value="d">
</form>
<?php
// Some coding with "$ca"
```

### ?>

### under a.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['c']))
$ca=f;
else
$ca=g;
```

### ?>

Now I'm in page b.php and my click on button "c" will redirect me to page a.php and set $ca at value f.How can I access to the value of $ca in page b.php?

Comment: actually what are you trying to do ??..:P

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="submit" id="btn1" name="btn1" />
<input type="submit" id="btn1" name="btn2" />
```

on page **a.php** you can check which button was submitted:

```
if (isset($_POST['btn1']))
{
    echo 'button 1 was pressed';
}
else if (isset($_POST['btn2']))
{
    echo 'button 2 was pressed';
}
```

Comment: <form method="POST" action="a.php">
<input type="submit" id="btn1" name="btn1" >
<input type="submit" id="btn1" name="btn2" >
</form>
it will print "button 1 was pressed" in page a.php but i want send the data "which button has been clicked" in page b.php by means of any variables

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code-

**on a.php page-**

```
<input type="submit" id="btn1" name="btn1" value="button1" />
<input type="submit" id="btn1" name="btn2" value="button2"/>
```

**on b.php page-**

```
if($_POST['btn1']=='button1')
{
  echo "button1 has been pressed.";
}

if($_POST['btn2']=='button2')
{
  echo "button2 has been pressed.";
}
```